# How do I change data in a ListView of a Fragment from a ListAdapter?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a Fragment which contains a few ListViews. I have my ListAdapter, which customizes the ListViews so that only one group will show a button and add an OnClickListener to that button.  I am trying to make the OnClickListener add an item to one of my lists in my Fragment, but the problem is that I cannot find out how to interact with any of the methods in my Fragment. Perhaps, there is also a better way to do this than directly through the ListAdapter.

SlidingMenuFragment.java - the fragment

```
/**
 * Adds a child to favorite locations section list
 * @param v the view
 * @param location the location to add
 */
public void addFavoriteLocation(View v, String location){
    mFavoriteLocationsSection.addSectionItem(99, "test location", "slidingmenu_clear");//TODO change dummy values
    sectionListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

SectionListAdapter.java - the list adapter

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slidingmenu_sectionview,
                parent, false);
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.slidingmenu_section_title);
    textView.setText(((Section) getGroup(groupPosition)).getTitle());

    //Sets the group "Favorite Locations" to have the only add_button as VISIBLE, and other groups to GONE
    //Set an onClickListener to add button as well
    if( sections.get(groupPosition).getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("Favorite Locations") ){
        convertView.findViewById(R.id.favoritelocations_addbutton).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//works
        convertView.findViewById(R.id.favoritelocations_addbutton).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {//doesnt

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //I am trying to call addFavoriteLocation(...) here, but can't figure out how to do so
            }
        });
        }else{
            convertView.findViewById(R.id.favoritelocations_addbutton).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Does SectionListAdapter hold a reference to SlidingMenuFragment? If so, you can use that reference to invoke the addFavouriteLocation function. Else you can use observer pattern.

Comment: The fragment passes a context variable to the ListAdapter, but it is the form of "this.getActivity()", so I believe it is passing in MainActivity, where the method and ListView I am trying to access are in the Fragment.

Comment: Why not call addFavouriteLocation from MainActivity using your Fragment instance? Activity will contact Fragments intance.

Comment: The problem is still that I cannot find out how to reference the methods inside MainActivity. I know I have it's context inside my ListAdapter.

Comment: Your Adapter should have a instance of your fragment or mainActivity. If it is MainActivity, write a method in mainactivity to call fragments method. if it is fragments instance, call it directly from adapter. Pass the reference in the Adapters constructor.

Comment: I moved the method to the MainActivity just for now, but the problem that still remains is that I still cannot reference it from my ListAdapter. In my ListAdapter, I cannot see any methods in my context that are from the MainActivity, or anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out...inside my OnClickListener

```
MainActivity mainAct = (MainActivity) context;
mainAct.addFavoriteLocation
```